# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cufflinks'

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, python-3.9

I have a problem. In cmd I installed plotly and cufflinks by using pip.
It showed my that everything is already in my computer, but when I am trying to run cufflinks and plotly I got an error.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
import cufflinks as cf
import plotly as pl
```

- Python version: 3.9
- Jupyter Notebook version: 6.0.3

Comment: Please post the error message too, might be helpful.

Comment: Make sure that the same python is used when `pip install`ing and to executing. How about to try `python -m pip install cufflinks`? Maybe your `pip` is not for your `python`, e.g., `python2` or another python.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-f5a26f003d70> in <module>
----> 1 import cufflinks as cf
      2 import plotly as pl

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cufflinks'

Comment: I used this command and it's still doesn't work :/ I have no idea what to do

Comment: DId you resolve the issue? Did the answer help?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments it is likely that you run Jupyter notebook from a different version or within a [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) which was not the one you used for installing `cufflinks`.

To ensure you are installing for the python version used in the notebook, I suggest you open another cell in the notebook and run:

```
!pip install cufflinks
```

The preceding exclamation mark ensures that the command is run in the command line of the currently used Python session.

And then rerun the cell where you are importing the library.